# PHP: Displaying checkbox array in email

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox

Question: HOW DO I DISPLAY SELECTED CHECKBOXES IN MY EMAIL?

I've created a survey (http://www.hello-rio.com/surveyonshoes/) and I'm trying to get my selected checkboxes to display in my email when the form is submitted. I'm a complete noob when it comes to this, any help would be greatly appreciated

Heres my html sample checkbox code (in index.html):

```
<label for="colors">What colors do you own? (check all that apply)</label>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="black">black </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="brown">brown </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="beige">beige </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="white">white </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="gold">gold </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="silver">silver </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="red">red </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="blue">blue </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="yellow">yellow </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="green">green </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="orange">orange </div>
<div class="twocol"><input type="checkbox" name="color_flats[]" value="purple">purple </div><br>
<label for="others">Others</label>
<input type="text" name="color_flats[]" class="others" />
```

and heres the complete php code (contact.php):

```
<?php

/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myEmail  = "johndoe@domain.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$subject         = "Survey on Shoes";
$Name            = check_input($_POST['Name'], "Enter your name");
$Address         = check_input($_POST['Address']);
$Email           = check_input($_POST['Email']);
$Age             = check_input($_POST['Age']);
$Sex             = check_input($_POST['Sex']);
$Status          = check_input($_POST['Status']);
$Employment      = check_input($_POST['Employment']);
$Income          = check_input($_POST['Income']);
$pairs_flats     = check_input($_POST['pairs_flats']);
$color_flats     = check_input($_POST['color_flats']);
$size_flats      = check_input($_POST['size_flats']);
$material_flats  = check_input($_POST['material_flats']);
$brand_flats     = check_input($_POST['brand_flats']);
$frequency_flats = check_input($_POST['frequency_flats']);
$cost_flats      = check_input($_POST['cost_heels']);
$pairs_heels     = check_input($_POST['pairs_heels']);
$color_heels     = check_input($_POST['color_heels']);
$size_heels      = check_input($_POST['size_heels']);
$material_heels  = check_input($_POST['material_heels']);
brand_heels      = check_input($_POST['brand_heels']);
$frequency_heels = check_input($_POST['frequency_heels']);
$cost_heels      = check_input($_POST['cost_heels']);
$height_heels    = check_input($_POST['height_heels']);
$work            = check_input($_POST['work']);
$mall            = check_input($_POST['mall']);
$events          = check_input($_POST['events']);
$travel          = check_input($_POST['travel']);


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $Email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your form has been submitted by:

Name: $Name
Address: $Address
Email: $Email
Age: $Age
Sex: $Sex
Status: $Status
Employment: $Employment
Income: $Income


FLATS
Pairs: $pairs_flats pairs
Color: $check_msg
Size: $size_flats
Material: $material_flats
Brand: $brand_flats
Frequency: $frequency_flats pairs a year
Cost: Php $cost_flats


HEELS
Pairs: $pairs_heels pairs
Color: $color_heels
Size: $size_heels
Material: $material_heels
Brand: $brand_heels
Frequency: $frequency_heels pairs a year
Cost: $cost_heels
Height: $height_heels inches


Work/School: $work
Mall: $mall
Events: $events
Travel: $travel


End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myEmail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')

    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
        return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

        <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
        <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

I've tried all sorts of codes like implode, if statements, foreach etc.. cant seem to get it right...

Comment: There a error on this line `brand_heels      = check_input($_POST['brand_heels']);` Missing $ at the start of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$color_flats = check_input(implode("," , $_POST['color_flats']));

$message = "...

FLATS
Pairs: $pairs_flats pairs
Color: $color_flats


...";
```

Comment: This is awesome! it solved my problem! Can't thank you enough, I've been stumbling on this code for a couple of days now. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Since `$color_flats` is an array, you need to loop on each

```
foreach($color_flats as $whatever){
    echo $whatever;
}
```

or you can implode it to make one and unique string :

```
echo implode(',', $color_flats);
```

---

```
<?php

#   Default Vars
$_color_flats = '';
if(isset($color_flats) === TRUE){
    #   Is Array ?
    if(is_array($color_flats) === TRUE){
        #   Count
        $c = count($color_flats);

        #   Loop
        for($i=0; $i < $c; $i++){
            $_color_flats.= (isset($color_flats[$i]) === TRUE ? $color_flats[$i] : '').($i == ($c-1) ? '' : ($i == $c-2 ? ' and ' : ', '));
        }
    }
}

echo $_color_flats;

?>
```

Comment: @GianAguilar Take the variable `$_color_flats` and echo it inside your message.